# Not sure why my function keeps returning the same value

Tags: c++, function

So I have made a program that inputs a number and then reverses it. E.g. input: 987 should return 789 but currently it keeps returning 32767.

I'm not sure why, I don't want to change my function but howcome it keeps returning the wrong value. The code inside my function `reverseDigit()` works, but when I try to use it as a function it doesn't work. Any ideas.

```
#include <iostream>


int reverseDigit(int number) {
int reverse = 0;

    for( ; number!= 0 ; )
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + number%10;
        number = number/10;
    }   
}

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int numberInput;

    cout<<"Input a Number\n";
    cin>> numberInput;     // Taking Input Number in variable number
    cout << numberInput << " reversed is: " << reverseDigit(numberInput) << endl;

}
```

Comment: Ummm... where's your return statement in your function?

Comment: I think you want `return reverse;` at the end of function.

Comment: Why don't you read it as a string instead of number and then cast it ?

Comment: Turn your compiler warnings on.

Comment: @Sylwit Why prefer to read as string?

Comment: @Sylwit will it work that way, I've never used strings before, the thing is if it ends with a 0 will it not print the whole thing. I need it to do this. 9780 to return 879 and exclude the 0 if it ends with a zero. Is that possible with strings?

Comment: off topic recommendation: Read the input like this: `if (cin>> numberInput) {cout << numberInput ...}` otherwise wierd things will happen should the user typing something that isn't a number.

Comment: Because with a string you can easily read char by char. You just have to prepend the result with each char while you are looping. It avoids all the calculation of the function. It's just an idea. If you need an int at the end just cast it and it will remove the initial zero

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning anything from your function.

This should have generated a compiler warning. If not you may want to increase the warning level.

Add `return reverse;` to the end of it.

With no return it's anybody's guess what you'll get when you print it.